# Git Push to bitbucket taking forever

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm very new to using Git and am using Bitbucket. I haven't had any issues until a few days ago. Sometimes my `git push` will take hours and will push over 3GB of data when my entire website is only around 20MB. The commands I'm running are as follows:

`git add -A`

`git commit -m "Some Message"`

`git push`

I've had no issues with this up until a few days ago when it just randomly started pushing massive amounts of data to the server that isn't part of the site. I have a feeling it might be caused by the `.git` folder but I'm unsure. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: `git add -A` is just lazy - target the files you've changed, or the folders containing files you've changed. Blindly adding everything is a bad idea.

Comment: By using `git add -A` is it literally adding everything in the directory or only the files shown by `git status`?

Comment: `git add -A` adds everything including file deletions. It won't add anything that isn't shown in `git status`

Comment: @RobbieAverill I think I'm gonna push everything this time and then just target each file after this push. If the issue is still there it must be something else.

Comment: @RobbieAverill I did a full git push and it's still tracking 2 files that don't even exist on Bitbucket or my computer. When adding only one file to the `git add` it pushes 102 files and takes about an hour and a half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up re-creating the repository and pushing only specific files at a time to prevent unnecessary files from being pushed.